# How to execute transaction in hibernate while throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following method in my transactional service layer implemented with Hibernate:

```
@Override
public void activateAccount(String username, String activationCode)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, AccountAlreadyActiveException,
        IncorrectActivationCodeException {
    UserAccountEntity userAccount = userAccountRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (userAccount == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s was not found", username));
    } else if (userAccount.isExpired()) {
        userAccountRepository.delete(userAccount);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s was not found", username)); 
    } else if (userAccount.isActive()) {
        throw new AccountAlreadyActiveException(String.format(
                "User %s is already active", username));
    }
    if (!userAccount.getActivationCode().equals(activationCode)) {
        throw new IncorrectActivationCodeException();
    }
    userAccount.activate();
    userAccountRepository.save(userAccount);
}
```

As you can see, in `else if (userAccount.isExpired())` block, I want to first delete `userAccount` and then throw an exception. But as it's throwing an exception, and exiting the method abruptly, the delete is not executed.

I wonder if there is any way to persist the delete action while throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced same situation too.

My solution was using **Spring Security FailureHandler**

with this Class, you can make actions after Failure Event.

See Here,
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler

Comment: I'd like to know what should be done in general, not just in security related code. I don't think I can use it though, because it's not a cross cutting concern to put it in a filter, it's part of the business logic.

Comment: You should checkout the logs to see if the extracted UserAccountEntity exists. (if null) from this code, I think It's confusing which block is executed. Becuase they throws same Exception.

Comment: It's definitely not null. I can see it both when I put a debugger and in the db. When I comment out the `throw new UsernameNotFoundException(...)` it deletes the row fine. I think this is what happens. In the transactional service layer transactions are committed when methods are finished normally, if an exception (even our own exception) gets thrown, the transaction is rolled back (i.e. not committed). I want to know how to circumvent this and tell Hibernate that it's fine and it should commit the transaction.

Comment: Apparently it rolls back because it's a run time exception: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/9600-preventing-rollbacks-when-a-runtimeexception-occurs